msbuild error: AssemblyRef does not contain a definition for 'Configuration'
I am 'migrating' a visual studio build to a batch script,
I have a one big project that has many dependencies,
i build my project with msbuild.exe using windows batch script,
the main project (client) has many dependencies.
i first build the dependencies, output them to their own directory (each one), and then copy the outputs into a folder called client,
Then, i build the main project (client) into the same directory.
msbuild command:
msbuild.exe <csproj_file> /p:SkipInvalidConfiguration=true /p:BuildProjectReferences=true /p:PublishDir=client_dir /p:OutDir=client_dir /p:OutputPath=client_dir /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=Release

I'm pretty stuck, and I'm the Devops that only migrates this build into batch and Jenkins.
It is fair to say that when building the project in Visual Studio, There are no errors at all.
Any thoughts?

not a direct answer, but you can try  to get binary log then use structured log viewer to find more details about the problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2022#save-a-binary-log

you can also try to get a binary log of the build from inside visual studio then compare those logs.

CS0117 is a compiler error. Are the projects .NET or .NET Framework? On the build machine are the appropriate SDKs and/or build tools installed?

Since you have built the dependencies, try to use -p:BuildProjectReferences=false in msbuild command to see if the issue persists.

@DouXu-MSFT
Thank you!
I have changed the configuration to -p:BuildProjectReferences=false, now the build succeed.
When opening the application (myapp.application) file, i says that a config.deploy is missing... am using clickonce. msbuild /t:publish

Structural changes
If you aren't already, I recommend using the SDK project files in your solution as they are more feature rich and are easier to edit. See this MS Learn page for more information on SDK.
First, delete all bin and obj folders in your solution. In my experience, VS caches a lot of build artifacts in the obj directory, often including the AssemblyInfo.cs file causing some of your errors.
After doing a real clean (removing all bin and obj folders), add the following to your project files:
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
</PropertyGroup>

This command will prevent assembly information from being generated. You won't want to keep this in your solution long-term, however it will be helpful for you in determinig the root causes of this error.
Depending on the amount of freedom you have in modifying your projects, you might consider adding the assembly information to your .csproj:
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>$(RootNamespace)</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(Version)</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>$(Version)</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

You can then attempt to recreate the successful Visual Studio builds by running the following command in your solution's root directory:
dotnet build YourProj.csproj -c Release -p:Platform="AnyCPU" -p:SkipInvalidConfiguration=true -p:BuildProjectReferences=true

If you're happy with how VS builds your solution, you can try running:
dotnet build YourSolution.sln -c Release -p:Platform="AnyCPU" ...

dotnet build calls MSBuild under the hood (MSLearn - dotnet build), so your build process will be unaffected.
On Output Directories
In your project file, you can specify the build output directory do that you can avoid specifying it in your script. Not strictly necessary, but you may find it helpful. This can be done by adding this to your project file:
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutDir>client_dir</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>


just an update,
I have changed the BuildProjectReferences to false -p:BuildProjectReferences=false, and now the build succeed.
my client needed me to add the msbuild /t:publish flag.
Now, when opening the application, is says that some app.config.deploy file is missing, which i don't know what is the source of the file.


error CS0117;AssemblyRef does not contain a definition for 'Configuration'

Since you have built the dependencies, try to use -p:BuildProjectReferences=false in msbuild.
For more information, please read MSBuild project properties

when opening the application, is says that some app.config.deploy file is missing

Could you find app.config.deploy file in your publish folder?
If not, please follow the  steps below to republish your project to see if the issue persist.(WPF example)
1.Create a publish profile in visual studio.A publish profile is required to publish with MSBuild.
2.Enter the following command.
msbuild /target:publish /p:PublishProfile=<pubxml file> /p:PublishDir="<specific location>"

3.Navigate to Solution Explorer, check that the App.Config's build action is still "None".

These steps produce a full ClickOnce application deployment in a subfolder of your project named publish. app.config.deploy is in the folder:publish\Application Files\App_version.

Docs Referred:
Reproduce the build from the command line

Thanks for your answer! few problems, In my project's folder properties, i do not have any file or folder refers to the publish profile. and when right click -> publish my project, i do not have an option to create a new publish profile. is there a way to that using CLI? or even from vs?

The easiest way to create a publish profile is by using Visual Studio. Do you mean you can't see  Add a publish profile after  right click -> publish your project? Besides what is the version of your VS and the type of your project?

Ok somehow, everything almost is fine now, now i have a problem which the .application files and app .deploy files are creating in a different directories. a application_files directory is created with all .deploy files but the .application file is created two folder behind ../../
msbuild.exe <csproj_file> /p:SkipInvalidConfiguration=true /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:PublishDir=client_dir_publish /p:OutDir=client_dir  /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=Release /p:InstallDir=client_dir_install

Hi @Shachar297, if you have more questions about A  ClickOnce application deployment folders, i suggest you can open a new ticket to discuss it due to "One question per post ". Just a reminder.;)
